# DrawRectangle в контролле меняющем размер

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно обвести границу контрола в момент когда он меняет свой размер. Допустим есть контрол panel с высотой = 100 и шириной = 0. В определенный момент его ширина скаждой секундой меняется пока не достигнет допустим 100пикселей. Задача в том чтобы в каждую секунду времени вдоль границ этой панели была отрисована линия. Для формы я использую такой код:

```
void Opac1ty::Border_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e){
    Skin^ sk = gcnew Skin;
    System::Drawing::Color border_color = System::Drawing::ColorTranslator::FromHtml(sk->l_p(send_forma->Name, "form", "border_color"));
    Pen^ pen = gcnew Pen(border_color, 2);
    e->Graphics->DrawRectangle(pen, 2, 2, send_forma->Width - 4, height - 4);
}
```

но проблема в том что при изменении размера формы DrawRectangle отрисовывается каждый раз когда форма изменяет размер и результат не стирается каждый раз когда форма снова изменит размер, поэтому в этом коде я отрисовываю только то что должно получится в конечном счете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При изменении размеров контрола по умолчанию инвалидируется лишь небольшая его часть, а именно та, на которую он увеличился. Соответственно, размеры `e->ClipRectangle` равняются не всей панели.

Простым способом, вероятно, будет инвалидация всей поверхности контрола при его ресайзе. Для этого подпишитесь на событие `Resize` или `SizeChanged` и в нём задавайте желаемую площадь перерисовки.

```
private: System::Void panel1_Resize(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    panel1->Invalidate(panel1->DisplayRectangle);
}
```

После чего событие `Paint` должно отрисовывать всю поверхность контрола.

Comment: Спасибо! Все четко.

Comment: Есть еще проблема, чисто эстэтического характера. Kонтрол, над которым находится эта панель, мерцает в момент изменения размера панели.
Возможно ли предотвратить это?

Comment: @Smirnov, [DoubleBuffered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx) должно помочь. Но лучше не в комментариях спрашивать, а отдельным вопросом.